# Making this CSS arrow box compliant in Safari and IE

Tags: css

A friend, produced this code, and I have refined it a little to suit our purposes. As we need white bg with 1px border version as per my fiddle.

However the arrow does not render in Safari and Internet Explorer.

Any suggestions: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/vHLJU/2/

Code: css

```
    #container{
position:relative;
margin:10px;
    }
    .rectangle{
position:absolute;
width: 200px; 
height: 100px; 
background: #fff;
border:1px solid #aaa;
    }
   .small-rectangle{
position: absolute;
top: 25px; 
left: 200px; 
width: 100px; 
height: 50px; 
background:#fff;
border:1px solid #aaa;
border-left:2px solid #fff; 
    }
   .magicrect{
position:absolute; 
top: 0px; 
left: 200px; 
width: 99px;
height: 100px;
border-right:1px solid #aaa;
border-left:none;
    }
   .arrow-right{
position: absolute; 
top: 0px; 
left: 300px; 
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 50px solid transparent; 
border-bottom: 50px solid transparent; 
border-left: 50px solid #fff; 
    }
```

html is:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class="magicrect"></div>
  <div class="small-rectangle"></div>
 <div class="arrow-right"></div>
</div>
```

Should look like this ...
[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: click the fiddle ! :) see question ( added image )

Comment: yes and i see something that does not look like an arrow, and I don't know what the exact shape is you are going for, so if you can get it to render correctly in a browser, please tell us which browser.

Comment: No arrow on Chrome/Mac https://skitch.com/bialecki/gn3nk/edit-this-fiddle-jsfiddle-online-editor-for-the-web-javascript-mootools-jquery-prototype-yui-glow-and-dojo-html-css

Comment: Displays on ff latest, 7.0.1 thinking should use rotate and progid

Comment: It doesn't display right in my Firefox 7.0.1 (Windows 7)... I get everything but the far-right-most angled lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a masked triangle to go behind the actual one as seen in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/BqGyU/

Basically the concept is to create two triangles. It appears the original concept was to have a white triangle (using a border to create it) on an off color background.  This is fine, but when you want a border around that, you can't use the border property.  To get around this you can create another triangle under it with the border color.  This is then off set to give the effect of a border.

```
.arrow-right-top{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 1px; 
    left: 300px; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 49px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 49px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 49px solid #fff; 
}
.arrow-right-bottom{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 300px; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 50px solid #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Argghh how close is that, havent tested in Safari, but in ie and chrome, theres a 1 or 2 pixel gap at bottom of triangle, great work tho !
Now tested in safari, yep just a one or two pixel gap.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this answer is that there isn't any actual code and/or an explanation. `:(`

Comment: Brilliant Joesph, voted. Also thanks to whoeveer voted me up, I hit 1,000 now thanks

Comment: @422 not a trick at all :) just change the borderLeftColor style attribute of the right bottom arrow

Comment: @422 This is not completely cross-browser... IE6 I think doesn't support it? but this is the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/bg37Y/1/ EDIT: or maybe http://jsfiddle.net/bg37Y/2/

Answer (score 4):

this is the best I got. you need 2 triangles on the end, one for the dark outline, and another to fill in the middle with white.

Edit: fixed the 1 pixel gap. you need to change the order of the html, and make the border bigger of offset it by -1 on the top, and -1 to the left.

Change your html to this

```
<div id="container">
<div class="rectangle"></div>
<div class="arrow-right dark"></div>
<div class="magicrect"></div>
<div class="small-rectangle"></div>
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
</div>
```

and add the css class

```
.dark {
top:-1px;
border-left: 52px solid #aaa;
border-top:51px solid transparent;
border-bottom:51px solid transparent;
left:299px;
```

}

this sets the first arrow that is behind the second arrow to have a dark color, and then pushes it out by 1 pixel so that it shows from behind the second arrow.

Comment: Good work aswell, yep similar problem to @joseph, there appears to be a 1 px gap at bottom of triangle ( arrow points ) but great work

Comment: Sterling effort, you guys are GOOD !

Comment: if you feel this is a better answer you should accept this one ;)

Comment: Will vote up your replies instead, as I had already selected best answer, unfair to reverse my decision.

Comment: @422 I second that... I won't feel bad if you revert best answer to this one.